# Mustache.js template with ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, mustache

mustache.js allow to use functions in view object, but how to push async function into template?
Here is my async fucntion:

```
var query = 'plot something';
var doQuery = function (callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://myhttp",
        data: {input: query},
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json) {
            if (typeof callback === "function")
                callback(json.result);
        }
    });
}
```

html

```
<div>{{{myresult}}}</div>
```

view object

```
{
   myresult: doQuery()????
}
```

Comment: You need something like http://backbonejs.org/ that can re-render the HTML when the AJAX finishes.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini no he doesn't and Backbone would not help at all in this case. OP, you just need to call Mustache.render inside your success function like `$("#yourElementsId).html(Mustache.render(json.result,template))` where template contains your mustache template and I assume json.result is your view object.